# vector calculus - Integral over vector

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Our physics prof wrote the following equation:

$\int\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}d\vec{r} = \int\frac{1}{r^2}dr$

This is logical as long as I argue that $\vec{r}$ and $d\vec{r}$ are parallel, which is why the dot product evaluates as $|\vec{r}||d\vec{r}| = r dr$ However then i tried to do it by hand:

$\vec{r}d\vec{r} = \left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\\ \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}dx\\dy\\dz\\ \end{array}\right) = xdx + ydy + zdz$

but this is nowhere near

$rdr = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2}$

which is why I would like to ask you what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

ftiaronsem

Comment: Your $d\vec{r}$ is not necessarily radial (and thereby parallel to $\vec{r}$).

Comment: hmm, why is that? I thought that this would always be true in clyndrical/spherical coordinates???

Comment: but your $\displaystyle{d\vec{r} =\left(\begin{array}{c}dx\\dy\\dz\\ \end{array}\right) }$ is neither in cylindrical nor in spherical coordinates.

Comment: ahh, yeah, ok convinced ^^. But even in that case I thought it would be true. Can you give a counter example?

Comment: The line integral in general depends on the whole line along which you integrate it (and not only on the endpoints). In general, $d\vec{r}$ points along the line and is not radially.

Comment: ohh, yeah correct. Thanks for clearing that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the following helps (it seems to be sloppy notation of your prof):

The integral $$\int_{\mathbf{r}_a}^{\mathbf{r}_b}\frac{\vec{r} \cdot d\vec{r}}{r^3}$$ is a line-integral. The vector field 
$$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}$$
is the gradient of a scalar field $\phi(\vec{r}) = -r^{-1}$, i.e.,
$$\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = \vec{\nabla} \phi(\vec{r}).$$ Therefore, the line-integral is path independent and the result is given by
$$\int_{\mathbf{r}_a}^{\mathbf{r}_b} \vec{E}(\vec{r}) \cdot d\vec{r} = 
\int_{\mathbf{r}_a}^{\mathbf{r}_b} \vec{\nabla} \phi(\vec{r}) \cdot d\vec{r}
= \phi(\vec{r}_b) - \phi(\vec{r}_a) = r_a^{-1} - r_b^{-1},$$
which coincides with the result of your prof.

Comment: thanks, for your answer, this is a nice way of solving the integral. I know nearly nothing about vector calculus so could you please explain why $\int_{\mathbf{r}_a}^{\mathbf{r}_b} \vec{\nabla} \phi(\vec{r}) \cdot d\vec{r} = \phi(\vec{r}_b) - \phi(\vec{r}_a)$? I tried to do it, which resulted at integrating $\int_{\mathbf{r}_a}^{\mathbf{r}_b}3d\phi$ after evaluating the dot product.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: this is called Gradient theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem). It is the fundamental theorem of line-integral (and replaces thereby the fundamental theorem of calculus).

Comment: ahh, I see. Thanks a lot. Originally I planned on rewriting the integral and solving it afterwards. I understand your way of solving the problem now, but can you help spot the mistake in my consideration? Would gladly accept your answer then ;-)

Comment: @ftiaronsem: (some formulas in your post don't make a lot of sense) To perform a line integral you should define a contour $\gamma:\vec{r}(t)$ with $t\in[a,b]$ along which you want to integrate $\vec{r}/r^3$. Then the definition of $\int_\gamma \frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}d\vec{r}$ reads $\displaystyle \int_\gamma \frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}\cdot d\vec{r} = \int\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3} \cdot \vec{r}'(t) dt$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field for more information. In general, the integral depends on $\gamma$. However, in your case it does not.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this answer. I see now how it is supposed to be done. You said that there are some formulas that don't make a lot of sense in my post. Could you point out where? I would really appreciate to know where i am making a mistake in the above considerations.